# alligation and mixture concept clarity

Tags: ratio

i want to clear my concept of alligation.
a vessel is filled with liquid, 3 parts of which are water and 5 parts are syrup. how much of the mixture must be drawn of and replaced with water so that the mixture may be half water and half syrup??
ti
i solved this question. and i got my correct answer 1/5...but i am confused how it works in allegation to get ratio of two elements using one elements in question??

like [this image explains basic method to find ratio of two elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbVv8.png) i have used this method and got my ratio 5:1 but dont know how?????
plz help....thanks

Comment: By the way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alligation

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what your question is, but perhaps you are looking for a way to write your solution mathematically?

We can do this very simply. Let the original (and final) total volume be $V.$ It follows that the volume of syrup is $\frac{5}{8}V.$ Now, let $r$ be the fraction of the original volume that is drained. Observe that the amount of syrup left after this operation is $\frac{5}{8}V(1 - r).$ This is equal to $\frac{1}{2}V,$ as given in the problem. Solving, we get
$$\frac{5}{8} - \frac{5}{8}r = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{5}{8}r = \frac{1}{8}$$
$$r = \boxed{\frac{1}{5}}.$$

And we are finished! Hope this helped.