# Mental arithmetic in Mixture and allegation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

A vessel is filled with the liquid,3 parts of which are water and 5 parts syrup,How much of the mixture must be drawn off and replaced with the water ,so that mixture may be half water and half syrup

I have tried:

Totally it contains 8 parts,

3/8       5/8

```
  1/2
```

1/8        1/8

Ratio is 1:1,for the mixture to become half,what i am doing mistake,is anyone guide me for the Answer,But the answer is 1/5

what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: This seems to be the same problem as here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862979/how-to-solve-the-given-problem-of-simple-interest If you are interested in clarification of answer to a previously posted question, you should say so and definitely link to the answer.

Comment: @naveendankal what i am doing mistake

Comment: I raised a duplicate flag because  it's just that this question has been asked before on this site and you can refer the same.

Comment: You can find the answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857822/alligation-and-mixture-concept-clarity